# Can I have a function used to help assign and validate properties passed as an object?

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I was wondering whether it was possible to do the following:

I have an object with 4 properties , defined as follows:

```
var Thing = new function(){
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.width = 0;
  this.height = 0;
}
```

Is it possible to define a set method which takes an object as an argument , finds matching properties and sets them to the given values and throws an exception if the property is not a member of the object.

So if I had an instance:

```
var thing = new Thing();
```

Then

```
thing.set({width: 10});
```

Would set width to 10, but

```
thing.set({radius: 5});
```

Would throw an exception.

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Because you have `var Thing = new function(){...` your `Thing` is already an instance of the anonymous function, which means that `new Thing()` will give an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would just need to add a `set` method on the Thing prototype:

```
Thing.prototype.set = function(obj){
   for(var attr in obj){
       // make sure attribute is not inherited from prototype chain
       if(obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)){
           // ensure that Thing has this attribute
           if(this.hasOwnProperty(attr)){
              this[attr] = obj[attr];
           } else {
              throw new Error("Property doesn't exist");
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Also `var blah = new function(){..}` should just be `var blah = function(){..}`

Comment: Great thinking. However, a) what if the target object doesn't extend `Object.prototype`, is a host object or has its own `hasOwnProperty()` property and b) [you shouldn't throw strings as errors](http://www.devthought.com/2011/12/22/a-string-is-not-an-error/). Also, your last part, it *is* valid syntax, just doesn't do what the OP probably expects it to (and will blow up when the OP attempts to instantiate it).

Comment: _"`var blah = new function(){..}` is not valid syntax"_ - Yes it is. It sets `blah` to an instance of the anonymous function. It's just probably not what the OP intends.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible for an object to *not* extend Object.prototype as it is the root level object that all other objects extend. Regarding the overriding of `hasOwnProperty`, that is a fair point, hopefully OP doesn't start off the bad practice of overriding default methods of Object. Thanks for the link on `Error`, don't know how I missed that all of these years :P

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for pointing that out, I reworded that in my answer

Comment: @RobM. `var obj = Object.create(null)` (often used for a bag of key/value stores, potentially passed as the object to this function) and it's difficult to know your environment when working with JavaScript (other libraries, third party scripts are common). It's also possible the keys could come from user input.

Answer (score 1):

Your first block is a bit weird, you shouldn't be using `new` there. Also, if you're going to use semi-colons, you should be consistent and place one after the closing brace of your function, since it's a function expression.

As for your actual question, that's indeed possible. You could extend a *subclass* which had this functionality...

```
Subclass.prototype.set = function(properties) {
    Object.keys(properties).forEach(function(key) {

        if ( ! Object.hasOwnProperty.call(this, key)) {
            throw Error("The target object doesn't have the key '" + key + "' defined.");
        }

        this[key] = properties[key]; 
    });

};
```

Then you could make `Thing`'s prototype point to it. If `Thing` is the only thing you want to work with this, simply assign it to `Thing.prototype`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting those improvements! And yeah it's my bad with the var Thing = `new Thing(){..}`